# Placing colored arrows alongside an edge

Tags: svg, drawing, graph-theory, graphviz, diagram

I am looking for a way to draw colored arrows alongside edges in Graphviz.  It must be possible to choose which side of the edge they are on, and it must be possible to draw multiple arrows of differing colors on each side of each edge.  The arrows represent packets of data, so ideally they should not touch the vertices.

[image: A diagram of a small network annotated with nodes "A", "B", "C" and red, blue, and green arrows besides most of the edges. Some of the arrows have a strike through them.]

I've looked at the documentation for [Edge Attributes](https://graphviz.org/docs/edges/) or [Arrow Shapes](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/arrows.html), but do not see any way to do what I described.

The goal is to create a simple web app that allows me to simulate a network algorithm and see how that algorithm plays out, to replace doing it by hand (above).  Any other suggestions for how to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question does not show any sign that you have done any work yourself sofar. Please only ask a question if you have a specific programming problem, not when you have noo idea how to use a software.

Comment: @ccprog I've read the documentation and do not see any way to do this, so I'm turning to StackOverflow in the hopes that somebody does. Your assumption that I have [not done any work is not a reason to close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417484/405550). I think the question is very specific.  If you disagree, please explain how I can clarify it.

Comment: Looks like ccprog (a very experienced SO user) didn't notice _your_ experience points. Had you not have that many points I could have easily replied _We are not here to do your job_ as well (a bit more blunt, because I am Dutch). Your question can be extended by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you draw the graph, and give people code to play with. You are now fishing for the grapviz-wizard who can write an answer off the top of the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is poorly specified, maybe the following can help.
In no particular order:

- The **Graphviz** language does not directly support the request (see below for *not-very-close*).  Either *Zaz* has to give up some of the requirements or will have to build a hybrid system that pre/post processes **Graphviz** output to get *close enough* to the desired result
- **Graphviz** edges do not have a definition of "sides", this has to be solved
- Labels and edges sometimes collide "normally".  Any hybrid system would have to try to minimize extra collisions with the added edges.
- The diagram seems to depict that some of the "extra" edges have diagonal slashes through them.  Again, **Graphviz** does not natively support slashed edges.
- As long as the "original" edges are built from straight-line segments (not **splined** or **curved**), adding parallel edges with a post-processor might not be too difficult (but see comment about "side")
- All-in-all, could it be done programmatically?  Probably.  **Graphviz** easily supports adding your own attributes.  And a **gvpr** program could (?) add the colored, parallel edges.  The **Graphviz Forum** (https://forum.graphviz.org/) has some examples of post-processing, though none too close to this request.

*not-very-close* (using **neato**):

```
digraph G {

  splines=false
  node [shape=point xlabel="\N"]
  edge [dir=none]
  
  a -> b [color="red" dir=forward]
  a -> b [color="green" dir=back]
  a -> b 
  b -> x [color="green" dir=forward]
  b -> x 
  x -> y
  y -> a

  c -> d [color="green:white:black:white:blue"]
  d -> e [color="green:white:black:white:blue"]
  e -> c [color="white:white:black:white:red"]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: You're awesome!  I was on the verge of writing my own layout engine from scratch, but I think your last example c-d-e will work with some minimal post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

*image editor*

Use graphviz to layout the graph with the black links

Edit the image with a simple image editor to add the colored arrows.

*text editor*

Use graphviz to layout the graph with the black links, specifying the **xdot** output

Edit the xdot file with a text editor to add the colored arrows you want. ( docs for xdot format https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/#xdot)

Use graphviz to process the edited xdot file and output the image file ( .png, .jpeg ... )